# Can your psicrystal fuse with you and give you construct immunities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics, familiars

Can your psicrystal:

1. Use Metamorphosis to transform into a living creature?
2. Wait until it's about to wear off and then use Fusion on you?
3. Have the Metamorphosis expire leaving you a construct/living-creature gestalt with a constitution score and construct immunities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take it from the top.

1. Yes. Metamorphosis, as per its description:

> You assume the form of a creature of the same type as your normal form, or any other type except construct, elemental, outsider, and undead. The assumed form can have as many Hit Dice as your manifester level, to a maximum of 15.

If a metamorphosing creature is any of these four types, it can transform into another creature of its own (usually prohibited) type, but any creature can transform into a living one using Metamorphosis. You can both share your powers with Psicrystal and cast *Self* powers on it:

> Share Powers (Su)
>
> At the owner’s option, he can have any power (but not any psi-like ability) he manifests on himself also affect his psicrystal. The psicrystal must be within 5 feet of him at the time of the manifestation to receive the benefit. If the power has a duration other than instantaneous, it stops affecting the psicrystal if it moves farther than 5 feet away, and will not affect the psicrystal again, even if it returns to its owner before the duration expires.
>
> Additionally, the owner can manifest a power with a target of “You” on his psicrystal (as a touch range power) instead of on himself. The owner and psicrystal cannot share powers if the powers normally do not affect creatures of the psicrystal’s type (construct).

2. You can perform Fusion during any moment. But, as per power description:

> Target: You and one touched willing creature of your type and your size or smaller
>   You and another willing, corporeal, living creature of the same or smaller size fuse into one being.

As such, unless both you AND your Psicrystal are of the same type, you can't Fuse. This practically means that in order to cast Fusion on your Psicrystal you have to either use Metamorphosis to both change into same type of creature (Humanoid, Aberration, Fey etc), or you both have to be of the same type in some other way (the easiest is to be Warforged)

3. No. You can't do that.

**Workarounds**

Depending on what you want to accomplish, you may have means to do variations on this trick to achieve the results.

1. If your goal is to be immune to Death effects and such, there's one simple solution. If you look at the list of creatures you can transform into, you'll see that it's more of a list of types you CAN'T transform into. Which means, that any type NOT on the list is a legit type for Metamorphosis. This includes Deathless type from Book of Exalted Deeds, page 157.

This type is basically what you get if you take Undead type and reverse negative/positive effects on it. It doesn't need to breathe, it's immune to poisons and death effects etc. It's as simple as Metamorphing into one. A Deathless is not a living being, so Psicrystal can't Polymorph into one and then fuse with you

2. Warforged are Living Constructs from Monster Manual III, page 190. Either be a Warforged, or transform your Psicrystal into one. How does THAT help?

Since Warforged are *living* constructs, they are not immune to several types of effects, including Mind-Affecting ones. That would open your Warforged Psicrystal to the possibility of using Mind Switch on it, which makes the process as such:

- Metamorphosis, on you and your Psicrystal. You into whatever you want, Psicrystal into a Warforged.
- Mind Switch on your Psicrystal, make it fail its save. As such, it's a living being now, and can be targeted by Fusion power. Your own type doesn't matter
- (optional) Another Metanorphosis into a more potent and less vulnerable Construct form as per your new (temporary) typing

  3. If you ARE Warforged, check with your DM if Warforged are a legit target for Fusion power. If they are, transform into whatever construct monstrosity you want, and change Psicrystal into a Warforged, then Fuse. Would work even better.

Hope this helps. If you had something else in mind, I'll try to cook it up as well

Comment: Could we get more justification for the claim that “If you target it BEFORE the duration of Metamorphosis expires (even if it's milliseconds before that), you Fuse with your Psicrystal at its state at THAT moment of time.”? That is kind of the pivotal claim in the answer, the one that answers the question, but it doesn’t have any explanation or evidence, it’s just an assertion. A really dubious one, in my mind—that logic would mean that _fusion_ could be used to extend any number of powers and effects, not just _metamorphosis_.

Comment: @KRyan The creature created by *fusion* doesn't get the effects running on creatures, though, except insofar as they provide ability score boots or whatever; instead, the fused being gets *only* what the *fusion* power says it gets, and it only gets those at the time of its creation. Once the fused being's created, it's statistics are stuck in a similar way to how a summoned monster's statistics are. (At least, that was my reading; I was still hunting for evidence that that reading wasn't nuts.)

Comment: @KRyan yeah, my bad, the "Target" clearly indicates that cross-type Fusion doesn't work. If you want to Fuse with your Psicrystal, either become a Construct, change Psicrystal into a creature of your type, or meet each other "halfway"

Comment: @Baka-Mastermind It is definitely *not* clear that if the type of a creature changes, all effects on that creature should re-evaluate their legality. That is a murky area of the rules that (to my knowledge) is not addressed anywhere. *Magic: the Gathering* has explicit rules for that kind of thing. *Dungeons & Dragons* (3.5e, anyway) does not.

Comment: It's a, more or less, generally accepted ruling. Since, say, a spell says that your Type changes to Monster Humanoid, for the time being you ARE treated as Monster Humanoid, at the very least for all effects that come into place from the moment your type changes to the moment it changes again (for one reason, or another)

Comment: @Baka-Mastermind Since the fusion gestalt is considered to be it's own creature with the benefits of powers manifested on the component creatures now just assumed to be part of it's default form, does it still have the former construct traits of the psicrystal since the metamorphosis power states that the user "lose any _benefits_ of the racial traits of your normal form" but doesn't say that you actually lose the racial traits?

Comment: RE: "…with the benefits of powers manifested on the component creatures now just assumed to be part of it's default form…" Why assume *that* instead of the fused being only possessing the abilities the *fusion* power actually mentions? (Ongoing effects aren't mentioned as being part of the fused being. For example, it doesn't seem to me that having a *protection from evil* spell effect on yourself when *fusion*'s manifested *transfers* to the fused being that *protection from evil* effect!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Is the fused creature still under the effects of the metamorphosis power and can it be dispelled if it is? Or is the metamorphosis effect rolled into the creature's default form after the fusion happens and it can't be dispelled?

Comment: @Cellheim I'd argue that the only ongoing magical effect that's on the fused being is *fusion.* The *fusion* effect creates the fused being that has its own stat block made up of what the *fusion* power says it's made up of. When the creatures separate and become themselves again, I'd rule that the *metamorphosis* effect resumes on the now-present creature from where it left off, for instance.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Well racial traits carry over and the _Metamorphosis_ text says you don't lose your old racial traits, you just lose the benefit of them. But losing the benefits of the old racial traits is not something that's inherited from _Fusion_ so are they now active once again?

Comment: @Cellheim This DM'd say to creat the fused being you look at both creatures as they exist right now and smash 'em together according to *fusion.* In other words, *it doesn't matter* that the psi-crystal has *inoperative* racial traits while *metamorphosis* is going as the *fusion* power looks at the psi-crystal *as it presently exists* to create the fused being. Racial traits from which the psi-crystal receives no benefit *remain* racial traits with no benefit when the fused being is created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77833/discussion-between-cellheim-and-hey-i-can-chan).